# How to remove a line by its number from file without rewriting file python

Tags: python, algorithm, file, io

I need to delete a line from a text file by its number, but **without rewriting a file**  (for performance reasons). I have a program that needs to remove and add lines to file very often. For example, I have file `test.txt` with the following text:

```
Hello, world!
Example
Sample text
Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Hello,
world!
```

and I need to delete line `'Example'` with number `num = 2`.

I have this solution:

```py
num = 2

with open('test.txt', 'r+') as f:
    for i in range(num - 1):
        f.readline()
    pos = f.tell()
    f.readline()
    s = f.read()
    f.seek(pos)
    f.truncate()
    f.write(s)
```

It works, but it rewrites the rest of the file (lines 3 to 6), which might take long.

I searched stackoverfow and google and didn't found solutions without rewriting.

Is there a way not to rewrite a file? Also, for more optimization, how can I find a position of the line by its number, without reading a prefix of the file?

UPD:

When I said not to rewrite a file, I meant rewriting the end of the file (delete it and then write it), because it could be very big, and just remove the line.

[@Kolay.Ne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11248508/kolay-ne), in a file I store just unique IDs of users, and user can add themselves or remove themselves. I think that txt file is a good solution for that.

[@DarkKnight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17580381/darkknight), I think that I could pad IDs with zeros to some constant length, and so I could just do `f.seek(num * (length + 1))` (*+ 1 because of the new line charcter*) instead of `for i in range(num - 1): f.readline()`.

Thanks all of you for help!

Comment: How can you possibly modify a file without rewriting it? Doesn't make any sense

Comment: You are looking for a database in my opinion. `sqlite3`  is simple and a standard package.

Comment: I edited my answer for the updated question

Comment: Yes, I think with db it might be much easier and faster, but to my mind the database is used when you need to store many data, like for example date of creating account, balance and others, which might be hard to pars in just text file.
I don't know what about speed of SQL queries, but I don't think that it is much more faster then parsing txt file.

Comment: @TimKostenok You think wrong. Your performance problem is entirely due to having to read/write extra lines of text. Databases solve that problem. Simply have a table with an index, and your performance problem will be gone.

Comment: Thanks, @btilly
I will try to use a database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way not to rewrite a file?

No, that's not possible. Typically, files are *physically* stored in file systems either as a contiguous block of data, or (given that the file is large enough) split into a couple of contiguous blocks of data. Thus, the task of removing something from the middle of a file is similar to the task of [removing a middle element from array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_(data_structure)#Comparison_with_other_data_structures) in memory: if you want to keep the tail of the array, you would have to move it back.

> how can I find a position of the line by its number, without reading a prefix of the file?

Again, that's not possible for the same reason: in your filesystem the file is stored as a sequence of bytes, not a sequence of lines (methods such as `.readline()`/`.readlines()` are a nice Python interface, which internally still reads the file as a sequence of bytes). So, there's no API to seek lines (and even if there was one, internally it would still have to read those lines).

> (don't ask for what)

That's generally a good idea to provide context of your question, one reason for that is to not end up with the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

In your particular case, perhaps, the technical question that you have, is actually there due to a poor design. Among other, I wonder:

- Do you really need to keep this data in a file? Can you put it to memory instead? If not, could you temporarily cache it in memory and only write it back occasionally?
- Is there a better way to organize your storage? Maybe you should have more than one file for your task?

As you provide no context, I don't know the answer to any of the above questions and can not recommend a conceptual improvement.

---

Now that the question is updated, we finally know that what you actually wanted is to track users, and their ids in particular. I assume you also want that storage to be persistent (that is, the users list must remain when your program is restarted).

A good fit for this task is a **database**. It allows one to store and manipulate data (e.g. ids and any other info you have) about entities (e.g. users) in an application. I would recommend you to start off with SQLite: it is a rather simple relational DBMS, which python supports out of the box, and there's plenty tutorials on the internet (just google something like 'python sqlite quickstart' or 'python sqlite tutorial')

Comment: I didn't mean rewrite file as you understood. File will rewrite in all ways, but I meaned to rewrite the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

If the lines on a text file are of differing lengths then the only way to get to a particular line number is by reading one line at a time.

In this case, the simplest way is to read all lines into a list, delete the appropriate element from that list then rewrite the file.

```
LINENO = 2

with open('/Volumes/G-Drive/foo.txt', 'r+') as foo:
    lines = foo.readlines()
    del lines[LINENO-1]
    foo.seek(0)
    foo.writelines(lines)
    foo.truncate()
```

If you don't want to rewrite the file then just keep the list in memory (having deleted the line that you no longer need)